# How are android nn_cts test cases created?

Tags: android, nnapi

NN_CTS test cases are auto-generated using some script. I'm trying to understand if there is any source code available for those test cases. The documentation is not very clear too.

1. Is there any source code where I can find script which generates these test cases?
   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ml/+/refs/heads/android10-c2f2-release/nn/runtime/test/generated/ : Test cases at this location
2. Is there any community where I can suggest/ask question to get prompt response?

Thanks!

Comment: Source code of all CTS is in the AOSP. I found the NNAPI stuff: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ml/+/refs/heads/master and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/neuralnetworks?autodive=0/ You might want to elaborate on why you are looking, as hardware vendors are the main audience (due to the binary blobs).

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang. Yes as per the link the test cases are auto-generated. I was curious to know how they are generated - like the script with which they are generated is it shared. I wanted to add some additional test cases to improve coverage.